# Current in an element in lumped circuits

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-circuits, electric-current

In a lumped circuit where we assume $\nabla \cdot \vec{J} = 0$ at nodes.
This could be roughly translated as the nodes don't accumulate charges.

Supposedly we connect an element like capacitor between two nodes, here charge does accumulates on capacitor then why do we have the same current on both sides of the element?
I do see that current entering one node will be equal to current leaving that same node... but how do we apply this same exact thing with two different nodes with an element in between?

How can we say that current entering one node will be equal to current leaving another node?

Answer (score 1):

Recall from the steady-state analysis of a capacitor that the charge on the plates are $\pm CV$, where $C$ is the capacitance and $V$ is the potential difference between the plates. As long as parasitic capacitances are negligible (as is the standard assumption in lumped-element analysis), whatever charge accumulates on one plate of the capacitor is accompanied by the exact same amount of charge leaving the other plate, so the total charge in the capacitor as a whole remains unchanged.

You can apply the continuity equation to a volume containing the capacitor. The only way the total charge in the capacitor can remain constant is if the current flowing into one terminal is equal to the current flowing out of the other. You can't assume $\vec\nabla \cdot \vec J=0$ on a capacitor plate: if there is current through the capacitor, there is charge build-up on each plate, so $\vec\nabla \cdot \vec J + \partial\rho/\partial t=0$ is the correct equation.

Another way to have the current density be divergence-free is to define a different kind of current by including *displacement current*. Using the continuity equation combined with Gauss' law:
$$\vec\nabla \cdot \vec J + \frac{\partial\rho}{\partial t}=\vec\nabla \cdot \left(\vec J + \frac{\partial \vec D}{\partial t}\right)=0.$$
$\vec J + \partial \vec D/\partial t$ is divergence-free. The second term is called displacement current density and is non-zero between the capacitor plates. The surface integral of $\vec J + \partial \vec D/\partial t$ is what people sometimes refer to when they say "current".

Answer (score 0):

In the [lumped-circuit description](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lumped-element_model) everything is condensed in resistances, capacitors, inductances and other such elements. Considering what happens microscopically in a node and writing continuity equation for it is manifestly not lumped circuit approach.

In truly lumped-circuit model, the conservation of current is included among the [Kirchhoff's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirchhoff%27s_circuit_laws).

Comment: But isn't KCL the same node equation $\nabla \cdot \vec{J}$ ?..we just wrote it in current density format. I am confused because I can't understand why we consider the current entering one node equal to current leaving other node.

Comment: At best, one can associate KCL with integral form of the continuity equation, not the differential one. And then it remains the difference between the *sum* and the *integral*, i.e., between a *lumped circuit* and a *distributed system*.

Comment: I didn't know that ..for context I had been watching this lecture (https://youtu.be/i9WixHfiZPU) where the professor assumes that speed of light in lumped circuit is infinite because the dimensions of the circuit is way small than the wavelength. Then from equation $\nabla \times \vec {B} + \mu \epsilon \frac {\partial \vec {E}}{\partial t} =\mu \vec {J}$ and as c goes to infinity product $\mu \epsilon =0 $ which would give by taking del dot of equation before and integrating wrt ds and substitution of $\int \nabla \cdot \vec {D} ds = q $ would give  $\nabla \cdot \vec {J}=0$

Comment: I think the problem here is misusing the term *lumped circuit*. You seem to have many valid questions, but you frame them incorrectly.

Comment: The lumped circuit term is actually used in lecture ..I am just using it as it is (at @30:19 into lecture) to distinguish the domain of Dimensions of circuit << Wavelength from two other domains microwave domain (where dimensions  $\approx$ wavelength ) and optics (where dimensions >> wavelength )

Comment: Have you followed the Wikipedia link given in my answer? Lumped circuit is a particular model, where all the properties of the circuit are collapsed to point-like elements.